# Using non-standart font in a web service

Tags: vb.net, web-services, fonts

İ am writing a web service in VB for creating a jpeg image as an output. I use a barcode font to print a barcode to the jpeg file. Since the font is installed on my PC it worked smoothly. But when web service is called by client the barcode is not there. Instead, the value is in the file with a regular font.

How can i print this barcode without installing the font to the client machine?

Answer (score 0):

How did you deploy the Web Service? For example: are you using terminal server to deploy the web service?

According to your text, from Visual Studio you're administrator and all it's all right. But same machine being invoked, not.

Then, when you deploy the service, you have to be sure that the user being used by the app pool, has enough privileges. Try that first.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio standart publishing. How do i see and change privileges of which user?

Comment: It depends on if you're using IIS Express or full IIS